# Loop for Correlation in R

Tags: r, loops, nested-loops, correlation

I trying to find a way to do a nested for loop in r to get every possible correlation combination of this:

`cor(y, column1* column2)`, 
`cor(y, column1* column3)`,
`cor(y, column1* column4)`
and so on

This is what I have tried so far:

```
for(i in 1:length(dataframe))
{
for(j in 1:length(dataframe))
{
joint_correlation(i,j)=cor(y ~ dataframe(i) * dataframe(j));
}
}
```

My dataframe has 115 columns like shown with a small sample:

```
FG_pct FGA FT FT_pct FTA GP GS GmSc  MP    ORB

0.625   8   0  0.00   0  1  0   6.6  28.4   2   
0.500   4   0  0.00   1  2  0   2.1  17.5   0   
0.000   1   0  0.00   0  3  0   1.2  6.6    1   
0.500   6   0  0.00   0  4  0   3.6  13.7   1   
0.500   2   0  0.00   0  5  0   0.9  7.4    1
```

I want to find the correlation for `cor(MP, column1* column2)` for every possible combination switched out for column1 and column2. This way, I wouldn't have to do every single one of them separately. If possible, I would like to save the output for each correlation combination `cor(MP, column1* column2)`, `cor(MP, column1* column3)`,`cor(MP, column2* column4)`, etc. in a separate column.

This is an example of what I want: 
[cor(MP, FG_pct*FT_pct)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cugwg.png)

Comment: Wait, correlation of what? The syntax `cor(y ~ var1*var2)` is not valid in R (`dataframe(i)` is not either). What are you trying to do? For instance if you simply want the correlation matrix, you can do `cor(dataframe)`

Comment: I want to do cor(MP ~ column1*column2), cor(MP ~ column1*column3), cor(MP ~ column1*column4), cor(MP ~ column2*column3), cor(MP ~ column2*column4), and so on. I want to get every single combination for column1*column2 since I have 115 columns in my dataframe.

Comment: And what is `cor(MP ~ column1*column2)` supposed to mean? As already explained, this is not valid syntax.

Comment: In r, try running cor(MP ~ FGA*ORB). You will get an output. I want to have the correlation for MP against column1*column2. I want each column inputted. What you have provided is not a loop.

Comment: Er, nope. It produces an error. Did you load a package that hides the default `cor`?

Comment: library(corrplot) is what I have been using. I get an output. I have added an example image in my post.

Comment: Then please add this to the question. Or are we supposed to guess? Note that the example you give is `cor(MP, FG_pct*FT_pct)`, **not** `cor(MP ~  FG_pct*FT_pct)`

Comment: I am sorry, I added the extra information now. It is actually, cor(MP, column1*column2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the correlations of every column multiplied by combinations of two of the remaining columns.

We can find the names of according combinations using `combn(names(dat), 2)` which we put into an `lapply`.

```
combs <- do.call(cbind.data.frame,
                 lapply("MP", rbind, combn(names(dat)[names(dat) != "MP"], 2)))
combs
#        1      2   3
# 1     MP     MP  MP
# 2 FG_pct FG_pct FGA
# 3    FGA     FT  FT
```

In another `lapply` we subset the data on the name-combinations and calculate `cor` with formula cor(x1 ~ x2 * x3). Simultaneously we store the names `paste`d as formula in an `attr`ibute, to remember later what we've calculated in each iteration.

```
res.l <- lapply(combs, function(x) {
  `attr<-`(cor(dat[,x[1]], dat[,x[2]]*dat[,x[3]]),
           "what", {
             paste0(x[1], ", ", paste(x[2], "*", x[3]))})
})
```

Finally we `unlist` and `setNames` according to the attributes.

```
res <- setNames(unlist(res.l), sapply(res.l, attr, "what"))
```

```
res
```

**Result**

```
# MP, FG_pct * FGA  MP, FG_pct * FT     MP, FGA * FT 
#        0.2121374        0.2829003        0.4737892
```

Check:

(Note, that you can directly put the names, e.g. MP, FG_pct * FGA into the cor function.)

```
with(dat, cor(MP, FG_pct * FGA))
# [1] 0.2121374
with(dat, cor(MP, FG_pct * FT))
# [1] 0.2829003
with(dat, cor(MP, FGA * FT))
# [1] 0.4737892
```

To sort, use e.g. `sort(res)` or `rev(sort(res))`.

*Toy data:*

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- as.data.frame(`colnames<-`(MASS::mvrnorm(n=1e4, 
                          mu=c(0.425, 4.2, 0.2, 3), 
                          Sigma=matrix(c(1, .3, .7, 0,
                                         .3, 1, .5, 0,
                                         .7, .5, 1, 0,
                                         0, 0, 0, 1), nrow=4), 
                          empirical=T), c("FG_pct", "MP", "FGA", "FT")))
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Jean-Claude Arbaut gives a better answers, as commented to this answer. Use cor(df).

Here is my botched answer: Using the library corrgram (Which is mainly a visual tool) we can easily get all combinations of correlations in a dataset. Example:

```
library(corrgram)

#Example data

df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(50, 5, 5),
               y = rnorm(50, 2, 5))

df$z <- df$x / df$y
df$abc <- df$x * df$y * df$z

#panel arguments are necessary if you want to visualize correlations
corr <- corrgram(df,
         order = F, 
         lower.panel = panel.cor,
         upper.panel = panel.pts,
         text.panel = panel.txt,
         diag.panel = panel.minmax,
         main = "Correlation")

#call corr gives
corr

             x          y         z        abc
x   1.00000000 0.07064179 0.1402051 0.89166002
y   0.07064179 1.00000000 0.2495239 0.08024278
z   0.14020508 0.24952388 1.0000000 0.14649093
abc 0.89166002 0.08024278 0.1464909 1.00000000
```

There is absolutely a better way for doing this with functions and without a package, but its early here, and if you are desperate to get the results this will probably do you fine.

p.s using the corrgram() function without assigning it will give you a nice visualization of your correlations.

Comment: But if you want the correlation matrix of a dataframe, there is `cor(df)` in base R. You don't need a package for that.